# Could someone explain this logic inequality?

Tags: logic

I've recently been in a logic class, and there's an inequality I really can't get my head to grasp. Probably because the quantifiers are too vague.
Here it is : $$(\forall x, P(x)) ~\text{or}~(\forall x, Q(x))\not\equiv (\forall x, P(x)~\text{or}~Q(x))$$

There isn't any more details, and I don't understand it. Perhaps because the "$\forall x$" is too vague, and doesn't tell if both properties $P$ and $Q$ are on the same set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The left hand side is saying:

> At least one of the following is true: (i) $P(x)$ is true for all $x$ or (ii) $Q(x)$ is true for all $x$

The right hand side is saying:

> For all $x$, at least one of $P(x)$ or $Q(x)$ is true.

The right hand side leaves open the possibility that both $P$ and $Q$ are false at some points. For instance, we could take $P,Q$ as propositions ranging over integers, saying they are even and odd respectively. Clearly, for any integer $x$, at least one of $P(x)$ or $Q(x)$ is true. But it's *not* the case that $P$ is always true or that $Q$ is always true. That's the difference; we can have 'alternating' truth values in the right hand side, but the left hand side restricts itself to one of $P$ and $Q$ being 'constantly' true.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we discover a new species X and want to classify members as plants or animals. The left side of the inequality states that either all members of species X are plants, or that all instances of X are animals. The right side states that all X are either plants or animals, allowing for the possibility that some X are plants and some X are animals. They are not the same statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace $\equiv$ with $\implies$ and get a true statement, but if you replace it with $\Longleftarrow$ the resulting statement may be false. So the LHS and RHS are not equivalent.

Example: $$x\in\{0,1\} \\ P(x)="x \text{ equals } 0" \\ Q(x)="x \text{ equals } 1"$$
Even though each $x$ is $0$ or $1$, it's not true that all $x$-es are $0$ or all $x$-es are $1$.

Answer (score 1):

It's the difference between

'Either all whole numbers are even, or all whole numbers are odd' (which of course is false)

and

'All whole numbers are either even or odd' (which is true)